Error el enviar todos los datos con Springboot a mi Front End
Estoy haciendo un crm donde controlo clientes, productos, proveedores y ventas.
Mi problema arranca a la hora de mostrar mis productos: todos los datos se ven bien menos el de Proveedor. Lo raro es que hice un Console Log para que me muestre los datos que me daba la llamada a mi api desde el frontEnd (con react) y no me aparece el dato del proveedor. Confundido fui a mi base de datos y al momento de pedir todos mis productos ahí sí que aparece la columna Proveedor_id.
Código de Producto:
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Producto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nombre;
    private double precioCompra;
    private double precioVenta;
    private int stock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    private Proveedor proveedor;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "producto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductoVenta> productoVentas = new ArrayList<>();

   
    public Producto() {}

    public Producto(String nombre, double precioCompra, double precioVenta, int stock, Proveedor proveedor) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precioCompra = precioCompra;
        this.precioVenta = precioVenta;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.proveedor = proveedor;
    }

Código de Proveedor:
@Entity
public class Proveedor extends Persona {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proveedor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Producto> productos = new ArrayList<>();

    public Proveedor() {
        super(null, null, null);
    }

    public Proveedor(String nombre, String email, String telefono) {
        super(nombre, email, telefono);
    }


Respuesta de la api:
"id": 1,
"nombre": "Producto d",
"precioCompra": 100.0,
"precioVenta": 150.0,
"stock": 10,
"productoVentas" : []

Respuesta de la base de datos:
"id": 1,
"nombre": "Producto d",
"precioCompra": 100.0,
"precioVenta": 150.0,
"stock": 10,
"proveedor_id" : 1


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Es que el uso de las anotaciones @JsonBackReference y @JsonManagedReference. Estas anotaciones evitan la serialización del objeto relacionado en una dirección (para evitar la recursión infinita), por lo que en tu caso, el proveedor no se está enviando al front-end.
Solución: Cambia @JsonBackReference por @JsonIgnore en la clase Producto o utiliza @JsonIdentityInfo para controlar mejor la serialización de las relaciones.

Hola Stina gracias por responder y por ayudar, pero no me funciono lastimosamente, ya que me sigue sin mostrar el proveedor y ademas a la hora de agregar uno nuevo me aparece un error.
